# checkbox checked inside bootstrap select box using php

Tags: php

I use following code to check a checbox while doing for each loop.But checkbox not checking based on array value.I used explode to create $newsource.Actualy I had 
sourceIds=100252&sourceIds=100111

```
    $newsource =  Array ( [0] => sourceIds=100252 [1] => sourceIds=100111 );

        <select id="source" class="form-control source" multiple="multiple">
            <?php $loop=0; foreach($sources->sources as $row) {
       echo $loop;
        if($newsource[$loop]==$row->id) {

echo '<option checked="'.checked.'" value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';

        }
        else {
            echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
            echo "a".$newSource[$loop];
        }
        $loop = $loop +1;}  ?></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($newSource[$loop]==$row->id) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'" selected>'.$row->name.'</option>';
}
else {
    echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
    echo "a".$newSource[$loop];
}
```

Comment: have you noticed  $newsource =  Array ( [0] => sourceIds=100252 [1] => sourceIds=100111 );.I think this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You're using checked instead of selected, and incidentally using it as a constant instead as of as part of the string

```
...
echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
...
```

Your code has other problems though: The array definition looks incorrect, you are accessing it as a plain array but the definition gives me the impression that it is an associative array.
And you're also referring to `$newsource` as `$newSource` near the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sourceSession = "sourceIds=100252&sourceIds=100111";
    $newSource = explode('=',$sourceSession);
      preg_match_all('!\d+!', $sourceSession, $matches);


<select id="source" class="form-control source" multiple="multiple">
<?php $loop=0; foreach($sources->sources as $row) {
        if(isset($matches[0][$loop])) {
                        $a = $loop;
                        $mtch = $matches[0][$a];
                                                    }


    if($row->id==$mtch) {
    echo '<option selected="'.selected.'" value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
        $loop = $loop + 1;
    }
    else {
        echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';

    }
    }  ?></select>
```